# How can I run a daemon on xampp using PHP?

Tags: php, xampp, daemon

I have an XML database that I want to manage independently from users on my website. Looking into the matter it appears that I should write a daemon script to manage my database. That is all fine and dandy but, I feel like I'm opening a can of worms. I wanted to write my daemon script in PHP, so I looked into PCNTL. But I quickly learned that PCNTL is not suited for web servers. So now I am stumped. How can I get a daemon to run on my server? Do I need to learn another language? I only want to write my own scripts. But I feel lost. I would prefer to write my daemon in PHP as I am familiar with the language.

I have been researching everything from PCNTL, CLI, SO questions, numerous articles on daemon processes... etc

I am running PHP 5.6.32 (cli), windows 7, on Apache. XAMPP 5.6.32. Unix system.

EDIT: I also have windows setup to run PHP from command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong in running a PHP daemon, however it's not the fastest thing, especially before the 7.0 version. You can proceed in two ways:

- Using `Cron Jobs`, if you're under Unix systems `crontab` will be fine, in this way you can specify the interval within the system automatically executes the specified script and then exit.
- The true daemon, firstly you need to change the `max_execution_time` in PHP.ini to 0 (infinite), then in your daemon call for first function `set_time_limit(0);`, remember to run it only once. However if there is some failure like a thrown error uncatched the script will exit and you need to open it again manually, and don't try...catch in a while loop because it will probably go into an endless loop. Execute the script with `php -f daemon.php`.

Comment: If I execute the daemon in the second way you described, will the demon run indefinitely, or will the daemon terminate when I close the shell?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I am getting a better grasp of it. A daemon script feels a lot like writing a server sent event script.